# Calculate area using simd_float3

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, ios16

Im using the new RoomPlanner API from iOS 16, and the idea is to calculate every wall area in meters, or at least the widht and height. Is there a way o calculate that using the object

`CapturedRoom.Walls` ?

Heres the object that im supposed to use;

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd_float3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate through `CapturedRoom.Walls`.

```
let walls = capturedRoom.walls
var totalWallArea: Float = 0
for wall in walls {
    let wallArea = wall.plane.width * wall.plane.height
    totalWallArea += wallArea
}
print("Total wall area: \(totalWallArea) square meters")
```

Comment: Is that an extension of some kind? I just get

`Value of type 'CapturedRoom.Surface' has no member 'plane'`